# How to extract the data from JSON file to write test case

Tags: json, unit-testing, testing, postman, testcase

How to extract the required parent/child node value from JSON output in postman.

I need to extract `model.ConfirmPassword` from the below JSON file.

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
  "model.ConfirmPassword": [
  "The password and confirmation password do not match."
  ]
}
```

What is the property to be passed in order to get that. `jsonData.value` is not working as I mentioned below.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Your test name"] = jsonData.value;
```

[image]

Comment: You mention your programming language. Is it javascript ?

Comment: @AedvaldTseh This screen shot is from POSTMAN. Yes it is javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Your test name"] = jsonData.ModelState['model.ConfirmPassword'][0] ==="The password and confirmation password do not match.";
```

Need to pass the index as `[0]` in `jsonData.ModelState['model.ConfirmPassword'][0]`
Otherwise it wont work if we want to access child elems.
It can be `[0]` or the specific index.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Before I missed that **model.ConfirmPassword** is nested in **ModelState**.

This is how can read the property:

```
var x = jsonData.ModelState['model.ConfirmPassword'];
console.log(x);
```

Here is the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/rCtVijwWpPgX7SdnP2ja

Comment: Not working

`var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);`

`tests["PasswordTest"]= jsonData.ModelState['model.ConfirmPassword']==="The password and confirmation password do not match."`

Comment: Remember @HarshaW that "not working" is not a very helpful fault report. As a software engineer, it is good to get into the habit of explaining _how_ something didn't work - were there errors, for example - otherwise you have given your helper nothing new to go on. Help people help you!

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the advice. I have posted the answer with explanation here.